# Generating a class that access a dynamic field (of a parameterized type) at runtime with ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am working with Java generics and I am trying to avoid Reflection as much as possible. For that, I found that byte-buddy could help me. However, I am wondering whether I can create a class (subclass of an abstract class) using ByteBuddy that allows me to reach out to a specific attribute of a parameterized type without reflection. Such an abstract class would look like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractClassTest<V extends Serializable, T extends AbstractEntity> {
    
   public boolean test( T entity ) {
       V value = getValue(entity);
       return value != null;
   }

   public abstract V getValue( T entity );
}
```

And an entity would look like this:

```
public class ConcreteEntity extends AbstractEntity {

   public String fieldTest;

   public ConcreteEntity(){
       this.fieldTest = "TEST"
   }

   public String getFieldTest(){
       return this.fieldTest;
   }

}
```

In other words, I want that my created class overrides the getValue() method found on AbstractClassTest. Another constraint is that I don't know what is the concrete AbstractEntity class at runtime, so I cannot refer to concrete types (i.e., I cannot refer explicitly to ConcreteEntity).

On the other side, the parameterized type V and the attribute name (e.g., "fieldTest") are known. That leads me to "tell" ByteBuddy somehow that in the overrode "getValue" method I want to read a given attribute of T.

Is that possible? If not, what other options are available within the scope of ByteBuddy?

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create such a class. Have a look at the DSL and `FieldAccessor` for creating (overriding) methods that access fields.

On the other hand, it seems to me that you should rather look at `MethodHandle`s which can access field values as fast as any Java byte code once generated. And I argue that resolving a method handle takes less resources then creating a class.

Comment: Thank you. MethodHandle seems to do the job!